# reach-router Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have read though the majority of similar questions to this and i cant seem to find an appropriate answer.

I have been following along [this tutorial](https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/journey-into-react-part-3-navigating-between-webpages-with-react-router/) and have got to Including the Router into our App.) in which it asked to make sure everything is working and proceed, However, when I run the app I get no output (the expected is "Hello world".

When looking at the console in Chrome I get the error

```
bundle.js:1003 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL ERROR MESSAGES**

There are additional error messages that were missed (window size meant they were displayed just off screen.

```
`bundle.js:1003 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`. in Router`
```

and:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

Both of these do generate a sstack trace but points to locations in the generated bundle.js

**END EDIT - ADDITIONAL ERROR MESSAGES**

Now I have checked my code to the one in the tutorial and it appears I have done everything the same. I have looked (to the best of my ability at this point) at the imports and exports and they appear fine to me. so I am at a loss as to what needs changing.

my code:

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/app';

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={App} />
  </Route>
);
```

app.js

```
import React,  {Component} from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

import App from './components/app';
ReactDom.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Journey into React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you do `export default () =>
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={App} />
  </Route>;` ?

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: norbertpy  - this removes the 'bundle.js:1003 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid'  - do you know why that may be or suggest some reading for me to better understand what's going on here?

Comment: Pineda - router version is 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok except that you don't need to put App both as the Route and the IndexRoute (you are misunderstanding something here)

replace your routes.js with >

```
export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App} />
);
```

I've no idea if that fixes your issue, if you provide a jsfiddle of your example I can drill a bit futher :)

Comment: This also removes the `bundle.js:1003 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid` error. However, there were a couple of other errors I have, that I didn't see because of the size of my window. i have added these to my question.

Comment: I haven't used js fiddle previously I will attempt to get it up there.